# Percentage value storage in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a percenatge value (6%) what is the prefered way to store this in the database
Solution1: 6
Solution2: .06
And why would you choose it?

Comment: I suppose that would largely depend on how you intend to use it. Personally I would store it as .06 as it means one less step in your code formula.

Answer (score 2):

Go for solution 2, it makes any calculations you have to do on it easier.

if it is 6% of the total {total (100)}*{db value (0.06)} = 6

easy

This also handles if you are going to have part percentages 6.35% would be 0.0635 whereas if you stored it as an integer of 6 you could not have these part percentages. The only real drawback of doing this is if you want to output the value back to the client in readable format, you would need to multiply the database result by 100 before outputting the result.